# Topological properties of $(0,1)$ with $B=\{ (1/n,1) \}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=(0,1);$

$$\tau= \{X,\emptyset,(1/n,1)\mid n\ge 2 \};$$

1)Compact: No.

There is no finite  subcover of $X=\bigcup_{n\ge 2}(1/n,1)$.

2)Hausdorff: No.

For $x_1\not =x_2$ there are no disjoint open sets $O,V$ with $x_1\in O$ and $x_2 \in V.$

Assume there are disjoint open sets $x_1 \in O$ and $x_2 \in V.$

Then there are disjoint basis elements $x \in (1/n,1)$, and $x_2 \in (1/m,1)$.

But $(1/n,1) \cap (1/m,1) \not =\emptyset$, for  $n, m \ge 2$.

3)Normal: Yes (vacuously).
(H.Brandsma's remark)

There are no disjoint closed sets $A,B (\not =\emptyset);$

Assume A, B are disjoint closed sets.

Then $(A\cap B)^c =A^c\cup B^c=X$, where $A^c, B^c$ are open ($c$ for complement),

this implies $A^c=X$ or $B^c=X$.

Hence $A=\emptyset$, or $B=\emptyset.$, a contradiction.

4)Regular: No.

Let $A$ be closed  and $x\not \in A$.

Assume there are disjoint open sets $O, U$ s, t.

$A\subset O$ and $x \in U$.

$O=\bigcup_{n\in I, finite} (1/n,1)$, and

$x \in (1/m,1)$ for a $m$.

$O\bigcap U \not =\emptyset$, and we are done.

Kindly check and correct, or give me a hint. Hopefully not completely messed up.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you claim that $(X,\tau)$ is not regular?

Comment: When you write $B=${ $(1/n,1) $} instead of $B=\{ (1/n,1) \},$ (the latter coded as `B=\{ (1/n,1) \}`, then you get a lack of proper horizontal spacing and a font mismatch, and other problems. See my edits. Also $\text{“}{\cup}\text{”}$ is used in things like $A\cup B$ and $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$ and $\text{“}{\bigcup}\text{”}$ in things like $ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ or $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n. \qquad$

Comment: Let $A=(0, 1/n]$ : $x >1/n;$ I cannot find disjoint open sets elements $x \in (1/m,1)$, and $A \subset \cup (1/l,1)$.

Comment: Michael. Thanks, I shall try to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refute Hausdorff you need two *specific* points that cannot be separated. So do the work.

If there are no disjoint closed sets then $X$ is normal voidly. ( we cannot refute normality).

For non-regular you need a *specific* point and disjoint closed set. It helps in the proof that all non-empty open sets of $X$ intersect.

Comment: Thank you. Edited part 2,3. Hopefully improved. Non-regulaity still needs to be done.